# nuxt build and generate throws error code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to generate a static website with nuxt and vuetify.

And when I type npm run generate/build im getting this error too but I don't know if its the reason.

ERROR Missing or incomplete config for current environment 'development': key 'databaseURL' is required!

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'd:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'd:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'generate'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v12.8.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'pregenerate', 'generate', 'postgenerate' ]
5 info lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~pregenerate: mywebsite@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~generate: mywebsite@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~generate: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~generate: PATH: d:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;F:\PROYECTOS\VUEJS\NUXT PROJECTS\mywebsite\node_modules\.bin;c:\program files (x86)\common files\oracle\java\javapath;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files (x86)\intel\intel(r) management engine components\dal;c:\program files\intel\intel(r) management engine components\dal;c:\windows\system32\openssh\;c:\program files\nvidia corporation\nvidia nvdlisr;c:\users\maattz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts;d:\program files\nodejs\;d:\cygwin64\bin;d:\program files\dotnet\;d:\program files\microsoft sql server\130\tools\binn\;d:\program files\microsoft sql server\client sdk\odbc\170\tools\binn\;d:\program files\git\cmd;d:\xampp\php;c:\msys64\mingw64\bin;D:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Python\Scripts\;D:\Python\;C:\Users\MAATTZ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\MAATTZ\AppData\Local\atom\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\MAATTZ\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\MAATTZ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\MAATTZ\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\MAATTZ\Documents\mis apps;D:\ffmpeg
9 verbose lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~generate: CWD: F:\PROYECTOS\VUEJS\NUXT PROJECTS\mywebsite
10 silly lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~generate: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'nuxt generate' ]
11 silly lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~generate: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mywebsite@1.0.0~generate: Failed to exec generate script
13 verbose stack Error: mywebsite@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (d:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (d:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid mywebsite@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd F:\PROYECTOS\VUEJS\NUXT PROJECTS\mywebsite
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "d:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "d:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "generate"
18 verbose node v12.8.1
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mywebsite@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mywebsite@1.0.0 generate script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263045/when-creating-a-new-web-app-within-firebase-the-database-url-is-missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When creating a new web app within firebase the database URL is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263045/when-creating-a-new-web-app-within-firebase-the-database-url-is-missing)