# When creating a new web app within firebase the database URL is missing

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js

When I setup a new web app in firebase I noticed that the databaseURL is missing in the config.

```
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: "",
measurementId: ""
```

Those are the only values I can get. I haven't created a realtime database. But I have no need to.

I am working with the firebase plugin

```
"firebase": "^8.2.7"
```

in Nuxt but it is complaining that the databaseURL is missing. I throws the following error

> Missing or incomplete config for current environment 'development': key 'databaseURL' is required!

So should I either get a databaseURL from firebase or is it a problem on the nuxt side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project in Firebase, it no longer immediately creates a Realtime Database for that project. For that reason, the `databaseURL` key is no longer included in the config, unless you've created a Realtime Database instance in the Firebase console.

Most Firebase SDK have been updated to deal with the fact that this `databaseURL` key is now optional, but it looks like you're on an environment where it is still required.

The two simplest solutions I can think of are:

1. Manually add a `databaseURL` key to the config. Most likely you can leave the value as an empty string.
2. Go to the [database panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database) in the Firebase console to create a Realtime Database, and download the updated config.

Of course, if you actually use the Realtime Database in your code, the second option is the only one that will work.